# TypeScript generic higher-order function returned function returned type

Tags: functional-programming, typescript

I have a higher-order function to create another function given a regular expression:

```
export function createParser<T extends { [k: string]: number }>(
  regExp: RegExp
) {
  return function (content: string): T {
    const matchArray = [...content.matchAll(regExp)];

    if (matchArray.length === 0) {
      throw new Error('Could not parse content!')
    }

    return Object.fromEntries(
      matchArray.map((match) => {
        const key = camelCase(match[1]);
        const value = Number(match[2].replace(/,/g, ""));

        return [key, value];
      })
    ) as T;
  };
}
```

The returned function returns an object of type `{ [k: string]: number }`, but sometimes I know a more specific subtype should be returned when assigning the regexp, so I'm passing a generic to the higher order function to be able to type the returned value of the returned function:

```
type A = Record<"key1" | "key2" | "key3", number>

const parser = createParser<A>(/* regexp that will produce type A result */);

const data = parser(/* some content to parse */);
//    ^
//    type A
```

Everything works as expected, but not sure if this is the best approach.

Any feedback in general is appreciated.